# How to make a 2D list with every element(list) is created by union of two other lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have two lists:

```
D1=[["a "," "," "," "," "," "],["b "," ","o"," "," "," "],["c ","x"," "," "," "," "],["d "," "," "," "," "," "],["e "," "," "," "," "," "]]

D2=[["a "," ","o"," ","x"," "],
["b "," "," "," "," "," "],["c "," "," "," "," "," "],["d "," "," "," "," "," "],["e "," "," "," "," "," "]]

D=[]
```

I want to make a list `D` so,`D[i]=D1[i] + D2[i]`,for example the first element(list) looks like this:

```
D=[["a "," "," "," "," "," ","a "," ","o"," ","x"," "],...]
```

Please help me I am new in python

Comment: `D= [a+b for a,b in zip(D1, D2)]`

Comment: **_I want to_** statements do not lead to questions - if you want try it. If you get to a specific problem with it - tell us **that**. As is - this is just a "gimme code for my problem" - you did not even show your [mcve] trying to solve it.

Comment: See  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and follow the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
D = [i+j for i,j in zip(D1,D2)]
```

if lengths are different it will cut the rest and go forward to the minimum of `D1`, `D2`. if you want the opposite, use `zip_longest`, like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

D = [i+j for i,j in zip_longest(D1,D2)]
```

But both will work if `D1` and `D2` have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

First copy D1 to D, if you don't want to alter D1. Then use `extend` method in python. It'll add all elements of list2 to list1.

Here is a simple code: though the time complexity of this code is O (n^2), it can be improved.

```
D1=[["a "," "," "," "," "," "],["b "," ","o"," "," "," "],["c ","x"," "," "," "," "],["d "," "," "," "," "," "],["e "," "," "," "," "," "]]

D2=[["a "," ","o"," ","x"," "],
["b "," "," "," "," "," "],["c "," "," "," "," "," "],["d "," "," "," "," "," "],["e "," "," "," "," "," "]]

D = D1 [:]
for i in range (len (D)):
    D[i].extend (D2 [i])
print D
```

Comment: @B.M. `extend ()` method takes O (n). Therefore altogether its O (n^2). For 
further information refer to here [link](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt)

Comment: My understanding is that complexity is O[ len(D1)*len(D1[0])]. no quadratic complexity here.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward from your will (`D[i] = D1[i] + D2[i]`), the simplest way is to use comprehension lists. Asumming `len(D1) == len(D2)`, :

```
 D = [ D1[i] + D2[i] for i in range(len(D1)) ]
```

will do the job.